# Adding a second form from Ajax output

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am working on an Admin module to a DB-project.
Basically user chooses a table from a dropdown and JQuery submits the name of the table to PHP which selects all fields, composes a  and echoes it.
Works like a charm.

```
function ajax_search(){ 
      $("#table_list").show(); 
      var search_val=$("#tables").val(); 
      $.post("./ajax/XXXXX.php", {searched_table : search_val}, function(data){
       if (data.length>0){ 
         $('#spinner_div').hide();
         $("#table_list").html(data); 
       } 
      }) 
    }
```

Now I would like to add a form under the table for adding one row. 
If I hard code the form on the HTML-page and uses a JQuery like

```
function ajax_add(){ 
      $("#table_list").show(); 
      var add_val=$("#manufacturer").val(); 
      $.post("./ajax/XXXXXX.php", $("#addform").serialize(), function(data){
          if (data.length>0){
            $('#spinner_div').hide();
            $("#table_list").html(data); 
       } 
      }) 
    }
```

I can catch that in my PHP and add a row.
But I would like to create the form AFTER I have submitted the first form because there are a number of different tables with different needs.

I have tried to add the form with an echo after building the result table like

```
echo "<form method='post' name='addform' id='addform'>
<input type='hidden' name='add'>....
```

The table shows up in the output and looks OK in Chromes element inspector. But the form is never submitted to PHP because the "Submit" is not caught by

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    .....
    $("#add_button").click(function(e){
        $('#spinner_div').show();
        e.preventDefault(); 
        ajax_add(); 
    });
});
```

Is it not possible to add a form after the page has been read the first time?

If I have been unclear in describing my problem I will do my best to answer any questions.

Regards

Mats

Comment: your new form should be out of old one, make sure your form should have its close tag. most of cases this is the problem check it

Comment: it's possible to add any element and associate event to it after page is loaded

Comment: Sudhakar: What do you mean by "your new form should be out of old one"